# Thread.sleep Issues in Web Browser

Tags: java, web-applications, browser, applet, japplet

Basically, I have written a JApplet and I now need to set a constant frame rate. I implemented a very simple segment of code that calls Thread.sleep:

```
long sleep = (long) (20e6 - System.nanoTime() + t);
if(sleep > 0){
    try{
        Thread.sleep((long) (sleep / 1e6));
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
t = System.nanoTime();
```

and when I run in Eclipse, all is good, but when I run it in a browser, the frame rate becomes extremely unstable and it looks like it's lagging. In the browser, it runs fine without the Thread.sleep call, just way faster than I need it to.

Any help on why this is or ways to get around this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Implement a client side buffering system

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, consider [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/subway).